# JPA criteria query in a many-to-many relationship using IN operator

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have the following two entities:

**Profile, Category**

In the Profile entity i have a List of categories that the profile has

In the Category entity i have a List of profiles that the category has

The generated table is called **profiles_has_categories** and has the following columns:

**profile_id, category_id**

I want to find all profiles that belong to any of the categories with the following ids 1, 2, 3, 4

I would do that in plain sql with:

```
SELECT p.* FROM profiles p, profiles_has_categories phc 
WHERE p.id = phc.profile_id 
AND phc.category_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

But i can't figure out how to do that using the CriteriaBuilder to construct a query in JPA:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Profile> criteria = cb.createQuery(Profile.class);
Root<Profile> root = criteria.from(Profile.class);

// Profile_.categories is a collection of Category objects
// categories is collection of Long (category ids) that i want to search in
// but is not working
criteria.where(root.get(Profile_.categories).in(categories))

List<Profile> results = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want a *get*, you want a *join*:

```
criteria.where(root.join(Profile_.categories).in(categories))
```